# Link ForeignKey record to its detail view in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

If there are two models

**models.py**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, null=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'a', )
    list_display_links = None
    ordering = ('-id', )

admin.site.register(ModelB, ModelBAdmin)


class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', )
    list_display_links = None

admin.site.register(ModelA, ModelAAdmin)
```

Is there a way to link `a` with its detail view in list view of `ModelB`? If not, then can we do the same in detail view of `ModelB`? That is, display `a` as a link to its detail view?

Currently in list view of `ModelB` there is only `id` of `ModelA`. And to view its detail I have to go to `ModelA` list view and search for the id. What I want `id` in list view of `ModelB` to point to detail view of `a` (like /admin/ModelA/{a.id})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields in the list view can be callables, so you can do this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'a_link', )
    list_display_links = None
    ordering = ('-id', )

    def a_link(obj):
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', reverse(
            'admin:myapp_a_change', args=[obj.a.id]), obj.a.name)
    a_link.short_description = "Model A Details"

admin.site.register(ModelB, ModelBAdmin)
```

Comment: What is `a` in `admin:myapp_a_change`? I tried both `admin_MyModelClass_change` and `admin_my_model_class_change` for my model class `class MyModelClass(models.Model)` but every time it says no reverse match found.

Comment: Thanks for the "fields can be callable" though. I remember reading it somewhere, just completely forgot about it.

Comment: "a" should be the name of your model. Go into the admin from ModelA and the url should be mysite/admin/myapp/the_class_name_you_need_to _use

Comment: If you still have trouble getting the reverse to work, just use `return format_html('<a href="mysite/admin/myapp/a_class_name/{}/change">{}</a>', obj.a.id, obj.a.name)`

Comment: Yep! got it working, thanks. Though MyModelClass name should be in all small letters, without underscore, like `admin:myapp_mymodelclass_change`.